# app could not be verified alert

Tags: iphone, device, provisioning

HEllo,

I am  quite new to iphone development, I am following the specified steps to test app on my device.

I have two provisioning profiles outof which none are expired. These profiles aare working fine on 3.0 devices, but when I  try on 2.0(iphone) devices it says application could not be verified.

I am using snow lepord and it doesnot provide simulator support below 3.0 thats why I have to test my app on devce.

Can you help me regarding this.

Thnx in advance

edit:

ok I think this one is done but now its showing "Failed to upload MyApp.app" due to which app appears in iphone but I cannot debug my code.

I have checked the tick box in entitlements.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google is your friend here.](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=xcode+3.2+app+on+2.0+device&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)

[Two good](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/build-iphone-apps-for-2-2-and-earlier-using-xcode-3-2-and-snow-leopard.html) [articles](http://hiddenelephant.com/blog/2009/06/12/targeting-iphone-2x-on-snow-leopard-with-xcode-32/) right off the bat...